# How to make the loop stop in this code when blank line is input in c

Tags: c, arrays, input, fgets

I need to make it so that this loop stops input when nothing is entered (the enter key is pressed) for charTeacherFirstName. I have this but the problem is that if the enter key is pressed the loop just keep asking for stuff as if it didn't read the blank.

```
int main(void)
{
    int intTeacherSalary[50];
    char charTeacherFirstName[50][50];
    char charTeacherLastName[50][50];

    do
   {
        printf("Enter the teacher's first name: ");
        fgets(charTeacherFirstName, 50, stdin);

        if (charTeacherFirstName == '\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Enter the teacher's last name: ");
            fgets(charTeacherLastName, 50, stdin);

            printf("Enter teacher's salary: ");
            fgets(intTeacherSalary, 50, stdin);
        }

  } while (charTeacherFirstName != '\n');
}
```

Comment: and your condition in the `while` is also wrong and useless because your `if` already handles it. Compile with warnings on and _read_ them. You won't even have to post here.

Comment: Also, you can't use `fgets()` to read `int`s into `intTeacherSalary`.  Or at least attempting to do so produces undefined behavior that is unlikely to be what you expect or want.  You might want to read into a `char` array and then parse out the `int` (if there is one) with `sscanf()`.

Comment: `if (charTeacherFirstName == '\n')` you cannot test string equality in C this way.

Comment: After seeing `fgets(intTeacherSalary, 50, stdin);` I suugest you need some time with a C tutorial sequence. Study how `fgets` works, Your target variable is an `int[]` array.

Answer (score 1):

At first your code is wrong. `charTeacher...Name` is a 2dim array and you don't use it like this. Then `...Salary` is `int` but you read it with `fgets` while its incompatible.

Also you cannot compare a `string` and a `char`, these things differ a lot.

So a char is what the name says. A single character. `'a', 'b', '!', '5'` are chars. When you do an immediate reference on them you need to put them between single quotes `'...'`.

Strings are let's say series of chars (`"abc", "food", "what a nice weather"`. You may think them as arrays, as you have declared them. They can also be declared as pointers on chars and then you will need to use `malloc(N * sizeof(char))` (or something like this) to get the memory needed for your operations. When you want immediate reference on a string you have to put it between double quotes (`"..."`). Strings have to end with the `NULL` character (that is `'\0'`).

I would say it is kind of the same you would say about `int` and `int []` or `int *` in each case.

In order to compare strings you need to use `strcmp`. Use `man strcmp` to see how it is used and what it returns as well as which library you need to `#include`.

Your condition should then be `if (strcmp(charTeacherFirstName, "\n") == 0) break;`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- You do not test the return value of `fgets()`.  It will return `NULL` at end of file, and you should not continue prompting for more input then.
- You should read the strings into the next array element for each array.
- You do not need a `do` / `while` loop, you already correctly test the end case, use a `for` loop and stop when the arrays are full.
- you read lines into the arrays but do not remove the trailing linefeed.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void trim_linefeed(char *buf) {
    int len = strlen(buf);
    if (len > 0 && buf[len - 1] == '\n')
        buf[len - 1] = '\0';
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[80];
    int intTeacherSalary[50];
    char charTeacherFirstName[50][50];
    char charTeacherLastName[50][50];
    int i, n;

    for (n = 0; n < 50; n++) {
        printf("Enter the teacher's first name: ");
        if (!fgets(charTeacherFirstName[n], 50, stdin))
            break;

        if (charTeacherFirstName[n][0] == '\n')
            break;
        trim_linefeed(charTeacherFirstName[n]);

        printf("Enter the teacher's last name: ");
        if (!fgets(charTeacherLastName[n], 50, stdin))
            break;
        trim_linefeed(charTeacherLastName[n]);

        printf("Enter teacher's salary: ");
        if (!fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
            break;
        if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &intTeacherSalary[n]) != 1) {
            intTeacherSalary[n] = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("%d teachers:\n", n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s %s: %d\n",
               charTeacherFirstName[i],
               charTeacherLastName[i],
               intTeacherSalary[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```